# ListView not updating after modal page actions in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, modal-dialog

I'm creating an application in Xamarin Forms. I have a TabbedPage with individual ListViews to show and handle coordinates and points. To add/update an item I created a ToolBarItem. This pops up a modal on a separate page. This modal has the entry fields with buttons to cancel (basically close) or submit the changes. The same will be used to modify an existing coordinate/point.
I have a viewModel (let's say main viewModel) that has ObservableCollection to populate the listview data, it implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and derives from BindableObject:

```
public class DataViewModel : **BindableObject**, **INotifyPropertyChanged**
    {
        private DataStoreManager dataStoreManager;

        public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Coordinates { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Points { get; set; }

        public DataViewModel()
        {
            LoadItems();
        }

        internal void LoadItems()
        {
            dataStoreManager = DataStoreManager.GetInstance();

            this.Coordinates = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>(dataStoreManager.GetAll<DataItem>(DataType.Coordinate));
            this.Points = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>(dataStoreManager.GetAll<DataItem>(DataType.Point));
        }

        public ICommand DeleteCommand => new Command<DataItem>((DataItem item) =>
        {
            dataStoreManager.RemoveItem<DataItem>(item);
            if (item.Type == DataType.Coordinate)
            {
                Coordinates.Remove(item);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Coordinates));
            }
            else if (item.Type == DataType.Point)
            {
                Points.Remove(item);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Points));
            }
        });
    }
```

This viewmodel currently handles the remove action only.
The xaml code looks like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModels"
            x:Class="Test.Views.DataTabbedPage">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="New" Order="Primary" Priority="0" Clicked="OnNewButtonClicked" IconImageSource="baseline_note_add_24.xml"></ToolbarItem>
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage Title="Coordinates" x:Name="coordinatesPage">
        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <viewmodels:DataViewModel />
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <Grid>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Coordinates}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" x:Name="coordinatesListView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="20, 15, 20, 0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Modify" Clicked="OnEditButtonClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                <MenuItem Text="Remove" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference coordinatesPage}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
    ...
</TabbedPage>
```

The viewmodel of the modal page derives from it, this is the dataEditViewModel. It should handle the update and new actions:

```
public class DataEditViewModel : DataViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DataStoreManager dataStoreManager;

        public DataItem Item { get; set; } = new DataItem();

        public bool IsNewAction { get; internal set; }

        public bool IsEditAction { get; internal set; }

        public DataEditViewModel()
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Item));
            this.dataStoreManager = DataStoreManager.GetInstance();
        }

        public ICommand NewCommand => new Command<DataItem>((DataItem item) =>
        {
            item.Type = DataType.Coordinate;
            dataStoreManager.AddItem(item);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
            {
                Coordinates.Add(item);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Coordinates));
            });
        });

        public ICommand CommitCommand => new Command<DataItem>((DataItem item) =>
        {
            dataStoreManager.UpdateItem(item);
            DataItem itemToRemove = Coordinates.Single(i => i.Id == item.Id);
            Coordinates.Remove(itemToRemove);
            Coordinates.Add(item);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Coordinates));
        });
    }
```

The xaml of this modal looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Test.Views.DataEditPage"
             x:Name="dataEditPage"
             Title="Edit Data">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:DataEditViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Entry x:Name="NameEntry" Text="{Binding Path=Item.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Entry x:Name="ValueEntry" Text="{Binding Path=Item.Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Cancel" Clicked="OnCancelButtonClicked" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Add" Command="{Binding NewCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item}" Clicked="OnCommitButtonClicked" IsVisible="{Binding IsNewAction}" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Save" Command="{Binding CommitCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Item}" Clicked="OnCommitButtonClicked" IsVisible="{Binding IsEditAction}" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Could you help me to out why the listview doesn't update after the collection change, like add or update? The remove action works perfectly fine, it updates the listview properly.

Thanks for everything!

(I also tried to invoke the actions on the main thread, but didn't work)

Comment: You have 2 VM classes, each with their own Coordinates property.  Adding an item in one VM does not update the other

Comment: The Coordinates is the property of the DataViewModel, the DataEditViewModel doesn't have it.

Comment: `NewCommand` is updating a `Coordinates` collection - where does this come from?

Comment: From the parent of the EditPageViewModel, from the DataViewModel. (I just realized, I didn't copy this viewmodel correctly, the class definition is missing. Going to update.

Comment: Regardless, each page has its own instance of the VM.  Changes to one instance do not affect the other

Comment: What could I do to make it refresh? In this case I need to somehow notify the viewmodel about the changes. Like a MessagingCenter? Or something else?

Comment: You could send a message, raise an event, share the Collection between the instances, etc